# Create multiple databases to a one system

Tags: sql-server, database

There is a one system that required to implement which has number of large users and number of queries for second.

**What** will be the best approach creating tables on a *multiple databases* or in a *single database* ? and **Why?**.

Comment: Single database is absolutely not desired when serving large amount of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend one database with multiple instances. You can set up Master / Slave replication between those database instances.

Some useful links:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html
http://members.cox.net/midian/howto/mysqlReplication.htm

Comment: Agree. Replication is needed to set up to synchronize among server clusters.